# Передача переменной с HTML кодом ajax

Tags: ajax

Помогите пожалуйста, при отправке переменной JavaScript, содержащей HTML код, с помощью ajax методом post происходит следующие

```js
var text = "<span style = 'color: red;'></span>";
$.ajax({
      url: "edit.php",
      type: "POST",
      datatype: "html",
      data: ({text}),
      success: div_edit
    });
```

```html
<?
$text = $_POST["text"];
echo $text;
// в index.php выводится это <span style = "\"color:"  red;\"></span>
?>
```

```
<span style = 'color:  red;'></span>
```

превращается в

```
<span style = "\"color:"  red;\"></span>
```

как это можно предотвратить? 
Код:

Comment: Очевидно, зависит от того, как чем отправляете и как чем потом читаете

Comment: PHP-код появился — прогресс) Но всё-таки как чем вы читаете переменную `$text`?

Comment: Появился echo — ещё прогресс) Тем не менее, я выполнил этот код у себя, и php мне вывел `<span style = 'color: red;'></span>` — в точности то, что отправилось в ajax. В общем, не воспроизводится ваша проблема

Comment: Я все рассказал

Comment: Но всё же код из вопроса работает абсолютно нормально и кавычек не портит, увы ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ничего не понимаю,  все проверил ещё раз,  не работает

Comment: Вы точно смотрите непосредственно вывод echo, а не результат обработки ответа внутри js-функции div_edit? Которую вы нам не показали.

Comment: Да, все перепроверено, это не может быть защита от вредоносного HTML или JavaScript кода?

Comment: Может, только если вы ещё что-то скрываете от нас, потому что с текущим кодом из вопроса всё в порядке и никаких защит там нет